# Using export from clara.io with three.js and physijs

Tags: three.js, webgl, physijs

I have a scene I exported from clara.io, and I can import it in a three.js scene. I modified MateiralLoader and ObjectLoader to add textures loading, but I'm facing a problem, cause I'd like to replace the standard meshes by physical meshes. I tried changing `THREE.Mesh` in ObjectLoader.js by `Physijs.BoxMesh` (most of the scene consists in cubes).

The meshes actually display correctly, no error in console, but there's no physics attached to it, no collision.
I thought maybe because the clara.io export are geometry and not just CubeGeometry, it might be a problem for physijs... I don't know, and I didn't find anything related. Could you maybe just give a direction for me to search? Thanks!

Here are samples of my code:

The script to export from clara.io, given on their website:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("zebra.json",function ( obj ) {
  scene.add( obj );
});
```

So I modified ObjectLoader from three.js: at line 287, in the case of loading a Mesh, i tried replacing this:

```
object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

By this:

```
object = new Physijs.BoxMesh( geometry, material );
```

And I also tried:

```
object = new Physijs.ConvexMesh( geometry, material );
```

Or:

```
object = new Physijs.ConcaveMesh( geometry, material );
```

I never gets physics (especially collisions) working, although the objects are well displayed in the scene. But collisions work well with for example a cube created directly from the script, using `THREE.BoxGeometry`, then using it with `Physijs.BoxMesh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out I was exporting the whole scene at first, from clara.io, and I was adding this scene into the scene I already had in my scripts. And in this case, the children displays but no physics, even if all scenes are Physijs scenes.
If I add only the children of the imported scene, it kind of works, although now I have problems with positioning, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to share a code example of the problem.  Also for arbitrary mesh data, you can use Physijs.ConvexMesh.